# XML con error en la ultima linea

Tags: xml

Tengo un archivo XML el cual no consigo ver el fallo por ninguna parte:

```
<xml version="1.0">
<dam>
    <class>
        <name>Lenguaje de Marcas y Sistemas de Gestión</name>
        <symbol>LMSG</symbol>
        <professor>Niveves Salaya Garrido</professor>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>Entornos de Desarrollo</name>
        <symbol>ED</symbol>
        <professor>Alvaro Diez Carrancio</professor>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>Base de Datos</name>
        <symbol>BD</symbol>
        <professor>Nuria Celis</professor>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>Programacion</name>
        <symbol>PRG</symbol>
        <professor>Carmen iza Castanedo</professor>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>Sistemas Informáticos</name>
        <symbol>SI</symbol>
        <professor>Pedro Jose González</professor>
    </class>
</dam>
```

Me gustaría saber dónde tengo el error, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por qué dices que tiene un error? Qué haces con él y qué error obtienes? Por favor, edita la pregunta y responde estas aclaraciones :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta en las etiqueta de apertura los signos de interrogacion

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<dam>
  <class>
      <name>Lenguaje de Marcas y Sistemas de Gestión</name>
      <symbol>LMSG</symbol>
      <professor>Niveves Salaya Garrido</professor>
  </class>
  <class>
      <name>Entornos de Desarrollo</name>
      <symbol>ED</symbol>
      <professor>Alvaro Diez Carrancio</professor>
  </class>
  <class>
      <name>Base de Datos</name>
      <symbol>BD</symbol>
      <professor>Nuria Celis</professor>
  </class>
  <class>
      <name>Programacion</name>
      <symbol>PRG</symbol>
      <professor>Carmen iza Castanedo</professor>
  </class>
  <class>
      <name>Sistemas Informáticos</name>
      <symbol>SI</symbol>
      <professor>Pedro Jose González</professor>
  </class>
</dam>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías tratar cerrando las etiquetas que no tienen etiqueta de cierre.

Por ejemplo, `<xml version="1.0"/>`.